# How to print and display all results of web scraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ""
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='simple-view')

events_elems = results.find_all('ul', class_='searchResults')

for event_elem in events_elems:

    date_elem = event_elem.find('li', class_='date-indicator')
    location_elem = event_elem.find('div', class_='text--labelSecondary')
    e_elem = event_elem.find('a', class_='event')
    if None in (date_elem,location_elem, e_elem):
        continue
    print(date_elem.text)
    print(location_elem.text)
    print(e_elem.text)
```

I just start to play with python web scraping function, trying to scrape on meetup.com with the above code, but only one set of results are shown, is there something wrong I did in the iteration section?

Comment: Your example is doing  the equivalent of `requests.Get("")`. Which makes no sense. Perhaps you made a cut/paste error. Which also seems likely given the incorrect indentation in the rest of your example. FWIW, You should not be scraping public sites like meetup.com until you have more expertise and have verified your program behaves sensibly when targeted at a web site under you control.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I had deleted the URL when I post, I have the URL when I execute the code. Would web scraping do harm to the site? cause I am only testing out the code in the text editor, that would be the same as browsing on the web right? That would be one request a time I run the code.

Comment: It is unlikely your web scraper would "do harm" to any web site. However, you should be "polite" and not scrape public web sites until you are reasonably confident your code works correctly. Your problem doesn't involve fetching the content. It involves parsing the content. So, it would be safer, and much faster and easier to debug, if you manually saved a copy of the web page you are scraping to your local filesystem. Then read that file and pass its contents to `BeautifulSoup()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.find_all` you used in

```py
events_elems = results.find_all('ul', class_='searchResults')
```

did not capture each individual rows from the website, i.e., you need to tighten the search criteria.

The `event_elem.find('li', class_='date-indicator')` you used are also insufficient, as it did not capture each individual event's date.

---

See the following working code, which capture the set of results by event-listing's container:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.meetup.com/find/events/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='simple-view')

event_container = results.find_all('ul', class_='event-listing-container')[0]
events_elems = event_container.find_all(class_= 'event-listing')    

for event_elem in events_elems:

    location_elem = event_elem.find('div', class_='text--labelSecondary')
    e_elem = event_elem.find('a', class_='event')    
    date = "{}-{}-{} {}".format(
        event_elem.attrs['data-year'],
        event_elem.attrs['data-month'],
        event_elem.attrs['data-day'],
        event_elem.find('time').text.replace('\n', ''),
    )

    print(date)
    print(location_elem.text)
    print(e_elem.text)
    print('-----')
```

with sample output of

```sh
2020-2-17 9:00AM


Architecting for Innovation



Australasian Enterprise Architecture Summer School 2020

-----
2020-2-17 5:00PM


Sydney Indoor Rock Climbers



Monday and Thursday Night Climbing @ St Peters (Beginners Welcome)

-----
2020-2-17 5:30PM

......
......
```

Comment: Thanks Tin Lai, I have tried the code, it works to display events on one day, how can I modify the code to display other days?